# How to combine corpus documents

Tags: quanteda

The example below is a list of 14 texts within a corpus. The corpus consists of 14 documents. I am trying to find a way to combine all the texts into one document. Then, the corpus would consist of 1 document rather than 14.

Comment: What example? I can't see it

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
corpus(texts(oldcorpus, groups = rep(1, ndoc(oldcorpus))))
```